# How can I set the Shell NavbarIsVisible with animation in MAUI of C#?

Tags: c#, android, maui

[Show/Hide navbar when scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76767407/how-to-implement-title-bar-hide-show-when-scrollbar-up-down-in-android)

In a ContentPage of MAUI, we can set the Shell.NavBarIsVisible by code when the CollectionView scrolling.

```cs
 private void HideNavigationBar()
 {
     if(ParentPage == null)
     {
         throw new InvalidOperationException("Parent page can not binding.");
     }
     Shell.SetNavBarIsVisible(ParentPage, false);
 }

 private void ShowNavigationBar()
 {
     if (ParentPage == null)
     {
         throw new InvalidOperationException("Parent page can not binding.");
     }
     Shell.SetNavBarIsVisible(ParentPage, true);
 }
```

But the operation is very wried. It is very uncomfortable. Is there any way to add an animation when the navbar toggle?

Thanks.

Comment: Since MAUI Shell API does not offer the animation for the scenario when navbar toggles, as in the previous post, you may need to use handlers and native code to achieve that function.